# Kafka Stream Metrics total windows

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

The process-total metrics is not clear to me.  The metric is documented as the "The total number of process calls".  Based on my observation I believe this and all this metrics are windowed (I think I read 30 seconds some where in the source code).  Is that true? I.E process-min is the minimum process time over the last window.  Are the built in metric windows customizable?

Are customer metrics windows observable?  If so how? This is how I create a custom metric currently:

```
StreamMetrics#addLatencyAndThroughputSensor()
```

The documentation was not very clear on this.
https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/monitoring.html

Comment: Think I found how the default window is set - metrics.sample.window.ms (30 sec default) and number of samples (2 default) - metrics.num.samples.  So my guess is metrics are based off the last minute of data.

Comment: That sounds correct.